# How to estimate multidimensional linear response function from measured input and output signals?

Tags: finite-impulse-response, transfer-function

Problem definition:
I measure *N* sources of noise $x_i$ and one output signal $y$ which contains real signal $y_0$ plus noise from all these sources $x_i$ transformed by linear response functions $h_i$ which are different for each of them. $\epsilon$ is noise from unidentified sources.  I want to estimate this multidimensional linear response function $h_i$ and subtract it from $y$ to estimate $y_0$.

$$
y(t) = y_0(t)+ \sum_{i=1}^N h_i * x_i+\epsilon
$$

the method needs to be fast (order of minutes) and robust ($\epsilon$ can be significant), N is about 100 and signals has about $10^6$ samples.

I have already developed a naive algorithm based on ridge regression estimates of FIR functions. Presentation describing this algorithm is here:
https://file.io/LANhPC5ccrhP

But if you could point me to the right literature or how is this problem properly called in the signal processing field, I would be very grateful.

Comment: Are $x_i$ correlated with each other? And are they correlated with $y_0$ and $\epsilon$? If both answers are not, you could use an H1 estimator: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/74617/frequency-domain-deconvolution-direct-filtering-vs-wiener-filtering/74618#74618

Comment: Yes, some $x_i$ are strongly correlated, but they are not correlated with $y_0$ or $\epsilon$. Estimating of $h_i$ is, therefore, an ill-possed problem.
Estimate $h_i$ by a Wiener filter was probably the first thing I have tried. Splitting signal in overlapping windows, calculate DFT, use Wiener filter to get $H(\omega)$, IDFT, get $h$ estimate for each window and averaging in time.  Results were still quite noisy if there was just one input signal $x_i$ and y_0 was zero. Also, it is not obvious how to generalize it for more inputs $x_i$.

Comment: Since they are highly correlated, can I assume that they are actually generated by the same noise source? Is it possible to reduce the problem as $\sum_{i=1}^{N} h_i*x_i\approx h_{total}*x_0$, where $x_0$ is the noise source and it would be helpful if you can measure that. $h_{total}$ is the total impulse response including multipath propagation and is what you want to estimate.

Comment: there are fewer sources of noise than the number of inputs $x_i$, but there are always more than ~10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you tried the DFT to get $h$ and the errors were higher than you expected.

Remember that the DFT does the circular convolution, let's say that you have $M$ samples, and you perform an $M$-point FFT, then there will be alias, unless the $h$ has only one non-zero point.

If you can use a bilateral response, i.e. a non-causal filter, then you just have to add some padding to the signal. But if your $x_i$ are uncorrelated there is no way to cancel out the influence of the end of the sample using the beginning of the sample, so, in order to match the zero-padding it will force the filter to have a short response.

If your $x_i$ ad $y$ samples have the same length and $x_i$ does not vanish at the end of the sample, the calculated error will increase as the duration of $h$ increases, it will make the duration of $h_i$ short, what is desirable in general. If the number of samples is large as in your case the error of the tail that is compared with the padding and the rest of the data tends to be small, so it should not introduce a huge penalty, this will decrease with the sample size.

Here an example of 100 x 29 point filter

[image: 128 point]

And another with 1000 x 25 point filter
[image: 1024 point]

Where $Y, V \in \mathcal{C}^M$ are the FFT of $y$ and $y_0$, respectively, $X, H \in \mathcal{C}^{M \times N}$ are the FFT for $0 \le i < N$, of $x_i$ and $h_i$, respectively, $\mathbb y_k, \mathbb v_k, \mathbb x_k, \mathbb h_k$ the $k$-th row of the matrices $Y, V, X, H$, respectively.

In the frequency domain your problem can be written as

$\mathbb{y}_k = \mathbb{v}_{k} + \mathbb{h}_{k}^T \mathbb{x}_{k}$

Since you have multiple possible solutions, what I would do is to choose the one that assigns minimium energy for $H$

$$
\arg \min_{\mathbb{h}_k} ||\mathbb{h}_k||^2 \\
\textrm{s.t. } \mathbb{y}_k = \mathbb{v}_{k} + \mathbb{h}_k^T \mathbb{x}_k
$$

Which is minimized by $\mathbb{h}_k$ colinear with $\mathbb{x}_k$. If we choose  $\mathbb{h}_k = c_k\mathbb{x}_k^*$, bing $c_k$ a complex scalar, and then $\mathbb{h}_k^T \mathbb{x}_k = c_k \mathbb{x}_k^H \mathbb{x}_k = c_k ||\mathbb{x}_k||^2$, from the constraint $\mathbb{y}_k = \mathbb{v}_{k} + \mathbb{h}_k^T \mathbb{x}_k$ we determine $c_k = (\mathbb{y}_k - \mathbb{v}_{k}) / ||\mathbb{x}_k||^2$, this gives us

$$\mathbb{h}_k = \frac{\mathbb{y}_k - \mathbb{v}_{k}}{||\mathbb{x}_k||^2} \mathbb{x}_k^*$$

All of these operations can be done in matrices, and you can use FFT methods to transform columns. So a very practical solution.

### Edit: Multidimensional example

As I mentioned in the comments, the formula above works for multidimensional data as well.

If you want to recover the one specific $h$ then this is not possible with the problem as posed. But for instance, if you have more constraints, at each iteration you can do a projection onto the space you are interested, this will give some approximation.

One example here with 10 x 10k points, where I want a 10 x 25 tap filter, I made a step to the direction of the gradient, followed by a projection that consisted in set to zero the the lower rows of the matrix $h$ (in the time domain). It converges to a biased solution accurate to 3 decimal places.

[image: error evolution]

Comment: Great idea, but it does not work for N >1. You are trying to calculate MN values of matrix H from M measured values of Y. Here is a testing code compared with simple least squares. 
https://www.sendspace.com/file/a98ghn

Comment: I just tested here, and and it finds a solution, maybe not the one you want. If you want a different solution you should use a different objective function. Maybe you want a short impulse response, that means a smooth frequency response.

Comment: I have tried to implement the algorithm following your description, and it really works. Only the convergence is very slow.  Any idea what is different? Code is here: https://www.sendspace.com/file/4xkzs2

Comment: The convergence tends to be slower as N increases, you could consider to do all in time domain, then you can find the solution solving an eigenvalue problem of the dimension of the number of non-zero terms in h.

Comment: This is some sort of gradient descent, you could set use a step size in your dh, e.g. `STEP_SIZE*fft.ifft(fh,axis=0).real[:L]`. Try STEP_SIZE=10 for instance. Large steps will make the convergence faster, very large step sizes will make the process unstable.

Comment: Your example converged to 10 digits precision, but notice that you are using as reference the full convolution, that may be a little unrealistic.

Comment: Thank you, this really helped me.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback :)